# JSP - sendRedirect is not working

Tags: jsp, redirect, glassfish-3

I have a simple jsp file:

```
  String url ="";

    if(aController.find(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id"))) != (null))
   {
        url += request.getParameter("name") + "&id="+request.getParameter("id") + "&__locale=" + LocaleUtil.setLocaleStringMail(request, response);
        url += "&__overwrite=true";
        System.out.println("this report has not been deleted");
        response.sendRedirect(url);
    }
    else{
     url += "error.rptdesign&__locale=" + LocaleUtil.setLocaleStringMail(request, response) + "&user="+report.getCreatorName();
        System.out.println("this report has been deleted");
        response.sendRedirect(url);
    }
```

it goes into first condition, does system out and send redirect. But it doesn't go into else and throws following exception:

```
[#|2011-07-01T16:29:08.595+0300|WARNING|glassfishv3.0|javax.enterprise.system.container.web.com.sun.enterprise.web|_ThreadID=29;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|StandardWrapperValve[jsp]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jsp.user.report_005fredirect_jsp._jspService(report_005fredirect_jsp.java from :74)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:109)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:408)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:483)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:373)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1523)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:343)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.labristeknoloji.lcas.client.filters.SingleSignOutNameAddFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutNameAddFilter.java:56)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.AssertionThreadLocalFilter.doFilter(AssertionThreadLocalFilter.java:40)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.util.HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.doFilter(HttpServletRequestWrapperFilter.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.validation.AbstractTicketValidationFilter.doFilter(AbstractTicketValidationFilter.java:167)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.labristeknoloji.lcas.client.filters.LCASAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(LCASAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter.doFilter(SingleSignOutFilter.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at com.labristeknoloji.lrms.web.filter.LocaleFilter.doFilter(LocaleFilter.java:76)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:329)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
    at org.apache.jk.server.JkCoyoteHandler.invoke(JkCoyoteHandler.java:229)
    at org.apache.jk.common.HandlerRequest.invoke(HandlerRequest.java:334)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.invoke(ChannelSocket.java:814)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket.processConnection(ChannelSocket.java:743)
    at org.apache.jk.common.ChannelSocket$SocketConnection.runIt(ChannelSocket.java:936)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPool$ControlRunnable.run(ThreadPool.java:682)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Do you have any opinion about this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The title says that sendRedirect is not working, but you wrote that it works in the 'then' block. If the control doesn't reach the 'else' block, then the problem is in the find method you use.

Answer (score 1):

That's the beauty of writing scriptlets in JSP. You can't figure out what's happening at which line. May be your `aController` is null. Just a guess.

Comment: Yes you are right aController returns null and because of this it throws exception.  I also wrote try catch statement, but it didn't catch the exception. Do you have any opinionabout what can be done in this case?

Comment: Create an aController object. Preferably Singleton object since you might want to reuse the same aController in other places.